Flutter Gridview.builder and AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin not working as intended
For my Flutter photo app, I am using a GridView.builder to build a grid of images fetched from the web. The image thumbnail urls are provided from my Image Provider, List<Image> [] which is initialized upon the app startup and is in sync with my database. The builder works great by fetching the necessary images that are visible to the user so the app doesn't overwork to load more than needed but the builder has to repaint if the user scrolls back to previously seen items. I'm wondering if theres a better approach because AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin doesn't work the way I was hoping.
GridView Builder
GridView _mediaGridView(List<Image> imageList) {
    return GridView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
      ),
      itemCount: imageList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final image = imageList[index];
        final CarouselParams params = CarouselParams(
          media: imageList,
          initialIndex: index,
        );

        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => context.pushNamed(
            mediaCarouselRoute,
            extra: params,
          ),
          child: MyGridTile(image: image),
        );
      },
    );
  }

GridTile Builder
class MyGridTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyGridTile({super.key, required this.media});
  final Image image;

  @override
  State<MyGridTile> createState() => _MyGridTileState();
}

class _MyGridTileState extends State<MyGridTile>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    final bool isVideo = widget.image.mediaType == 'video';
    final url = widget.image.thumbnailUrl;

    Future<int> getHttpStatus() async {
      try {
        return await http
            .head(Uri.parse(widget.image.thumbnailUrl))
            .then((response) {
          return response.statusCode;
        });
      } catch (e) {
        debugPrint(e.toString());
      }
      return 404;
    }

    return FutureBuilder<int>(
      future: getHttpStatus(),
      builder: (context, snap) {
        if (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive());
        } else if (snap.hasError || !snap.hasData) {
          return const Center(
              child: Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.red, size: 26));
        } else if (snap.data == 404) {
          return const Center(
              child: Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.red, size: 26));
        } else if (snap.data == 403) {
          return const Center(
              child: Icon(Icons.warning, color: Colors.yellow, size: 26));
        }

        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(url),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: isVideo
              ? const Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: Colors.white),
                )
              : null,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

What I have below is a gridview.builder that creates a stateful widget for each tile. This seems highly inefficient because my list of Image objects will contain thousands of image thumbnail urls.
I also thought of RepaintBoundary for each item or the gridview itself but i worry that it would be costly on the device cache system. And since I'm already using the cachednetworkimage, i thought there'd be a better solution.

I also now realize that Gridview.builder comes with automatickeepalives and addrepaintboundaries set to true, so how come the debugRepaintRainbow is showing repaintings of every tile in my gridview?
